# Applying as a temporary representative in Germany for a non-EU company without a German subsidiary

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit

I am a non-EU citizen currently living in Berlin on a post-studies 18 month job search visa, and looking into options to get a residence/work permit. I have the option to work remotely for a non-EU company based in Ecuador, and it is possible that they would like like to establish a presence in German

After reading a few related posts on this site, the most relevant one i could find was this: [Residence/work permit in Germany when working remotely for US company without German subsidiary](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6878/residence-work-permit-in-germany-when-working-remotely-for-us-company-without-ge)

I am currently in the talks with the Berlin Partners, on options for me to register here as a "temporary representative" of my company, and they have recommended that I speak to a lawyer (which i will). In the meantime, I would greatly appreciate any insights on what this application process would entail (for me, for the company) e.g. what documents are required (apart from a letter of authorisation and my contract), whether the company needs to pay any additional fees or charges apart from my social security and taxes), any recommendations of english-speaking law firms in berlin etc.

Any other recommendations on my situation would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!